# Safari deals with content within a ul/li differently than Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

So I have this neat horizontal expanding menu I'm working on and have ran into an odd issue while testing browser compatibility.

It seems that Safari handles content differently than Chrome with respect the amount of content within a li.

```css
/* CSS for raw HTML elements */
body {
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 950px;
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70vh;
  padding-top: 15vh;
  padding-left: 2vw;
  font-size: 0;
}

#tabs {
  z-index: 2;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 4vw;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.8s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

#tabs:focus {
  outline: none;
  width: 50vw;
}

.h1-tab {
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: -1vw;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.h1-tab::after {
  content: "";
  padding: 2vw;
  position: absolute;
  width: 62.5vh;
  left: -20px;
  top: -22px;
}

.products {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.about {
  background-color: orange;
}

.news {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.contact {
  background-color: red;
}

.paragraph {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding: 50px 0 0 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgb(204,204,204);
}

.paragraph p {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="test" class="accordion">
      <li id="tabs" tabindex="-1" class="products">
        <h1 class="h1-tab">products</h1>
          <div class="paragraph">
            <h1>Products</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="tabs" tabindex="-1" class="about">
          <h1 class="h1-tab">about</h1>
          <div class="paragraph">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <p>this li has an extra paragraph of information and messes up the whole structure when viewing this in safari. in chrome it works fine. what the heeeecccck</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="tabs" tabindex="-1" class="news">
          <h1 class="h1-tab">news</h1>
          <div class="paragraph">
            <h1>News</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li id="tabs" tabindex="-1" class="contact">
          <h1 class="h1-tab">contact</h1>
          <div class="paragraph">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/2bnf65yo/6/

If you view it in Chrome it works fine and behaves as intended. However, switching to Safari will show one of the menu bars (the one with extra content in it) askew from the rest.

I cannot tell if this is a Safari behavior specific to li's or is it something else with my specific menu setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically if you're using `display: inline-block` with elements of varying size/content, you'll want to use the `vertical-align` CSS property to ensure that your content stays lined up.

**Add `vertical-align: top` to your `li` elements to fix the Safari issue.**

Also, it looks like you're using classes and IDs in the opposite way they're meant to be used. IDs should be unique (only occurring once in a page), while classes are meant to be reused.

In other words:

```
<li id="tabs" tabindex="-1" class="products">
<li id="tabs" tabindex="-1" class="about">
```

Should be:

```
<li class="tabs" tabindex="-1" id="products">
<li class="tabs" tabindex="-1" id="about">
```

Comment: boy do I feel dumb, didn't even think about vertical-align!!!
and ya don't worry about the class/id mixups. I built this up quickly and wasn't bothering with the correctness for the time being.
lack of sleep == brain farts
Thanks for your help tho!